# Azure SQL Data Migration Assistant is Stuck on “Migrate Data”

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, data-migration

I am in the process of using the Data Migration Assistant to move a local DB to Aszure SQL.  The schema transfer went well, and 243 of the 246 tables all were able to transfer their data with no errors.

However, the transfer has been running for 13+ hours, and over the last three hours, three of the tables have not budged on their percent complete.  One is at 92.3%, one is at 93.9%, and the last is at 98.5%.

Some questions:

- At this point, can I safely assume that this is a failed transfer, at least of these three tables?
- I don't see a "stop" button.  If I wanted to, how would I abort this process?
- If I were to abort the process, is there some way to manually finish the transfer of data from just these three tables?

Comment: Hello Casey. I shared your thread on an internal mailing list at Microsoft, and  one of the Microsoft engineers interested in your thread would like to examine DMA logs located at <system drive>\Users\gennadyk\AppData\Local\DataMigrationAssistant. Could you possible put the content of that folder on your Public folder on OneDrive and share the URL with us. My e-mail is alberto_morillo @ Hotmail, if needed.

Comment: Will do!! I'll email you a zip file with all of the logs.  I've done a lot since I posted this.  I went back and did the three tables individually. One of them had 40 million plus records.  I whittled that down to ~3 million in the source db and did it again.. Just saying, they will have a lot of logs to dig though.

Comment: Sorry for my late response , I started to look for help on your case prior to even contact you and since you did not find help I know you have to try to find a workaround. Please send me an email with the content of that folder to alberto_morillo @ Hotmail.com. The content of that folder should still be useful. If you have a DropBox account or similar, please ulpload the content to that account and share with us the URL.

Comment: After making sure the logs didn't contain any sensitive data (passwords, etc), I zipped them up and emailed them to you.

Comment: I received your email. I am forwarding those logs to Microsoft engineer. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thank your for allowing us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Microsoft Engineer examined the logs you shared with us and found the following error:

> Dma.exe Information: 0 : 'Exception type: System.IO.IOException
>       Message: 
>           There is not enough space on the disk.

It seems like workstation that DMA is running on doesn’t have enough disk space to do schema extract.

The following is the explanation the Microsoft engineer shared with us about why DMA requires disk space:

> The Extract service connects to a database, reads all of its objects
>   and their properties, and then creates an in-memory model of the
>   database. Similar to how the Build service validates the defined
>   objects, the Extract service also checks for consistency and
>   containment. The validation done here will also result in failures if
>   you have a view that refers to a non-existent table same as with
>   T-SQL! Additionally, unsupported or uncontained objects are blocked
>   because these objects are not yet allowed in SQL Azure or the DAC
>   in-memory model. Finally, once the in-memory model is complete and
>   validated, a DACPAC is written to disk. Looking at the stack it’s a
>   well-known Windows exception on not enough disk space.